# Rails and Angular templating not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So currently I'm trying to mash up Rails and AngularJS in one server. My previous application was the client and the backend was in a separate server. Yesterday, I was searching what is the best way to integrate Rails and AngularJS. So, I found this tutorial and followed it: http://start.jcolemorrison.com/angularjs-rails-4-1-and-ui-router-tutorial/

One thing I experienced is when I try to integrate with the templates of Angular I got a blank page. Totally, I've been searching lot of solution to solve this but sadly it didn't work.

Files:

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ../templates
```

bower.json

```
"lib": {
    "name": "bower-rails generated lib assets",
    "dependencies": {
      "angular": "latest",
      "angular-ui-router": "latest",
      "angular-animate": "latest",
      "bootstrap-sass-official": "latest",
      "angular-devise": "latest"
      // "threex"      : "git@github.com:rharriso/threex.git",
      // "gsvpano.js"  : "https://github.com/rharriso/GSVPano.js/blob/master/src/GSVPano.js"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answer this problem. My naming convention had a conflict with the other files. Assets and other files are okay. Thanks.